# Get previous command in docker container console

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

Docker-toolbox is installed on the windows machine. I go into the container, for example: `docker exec -it web / bin / sh` I can enter commands there.

How to access the history of input commands inside a container? In all consoles, this is done using the `up arrow key`, here when you press this key, `^ [[A.`

How to look at the history or at least call the previous command?

Comment: Use a more powerful shell, if you have one; some containers (but not all) will have `/bin/bash`.

Comment: thank you. bin/bash - solution

Comment: @sveta600 What shell did you end up using to fix this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The easier way is to type the command "bash" and then you'll be in bash with previous commands history.

Comment: You made my day! This solution is easy and worked like a charm! You have my million thanks!

Answer (score 20):

As @DavidMaze pointed out, regular shell located in `/bin/sh` doesn't have the history feature unlike `bash` located (simply put) in `/bin/bash`

related threads can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307580/up-arrow-for-history-does-not-work-over-ssh) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325807/arrow-keys-home-end-tab-complete-keys-not-working-in-shell), and a more detailed explanation about the difference between the two can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141928/what-is-the-difference-between-bin-sh-and-bin-bash)

**Usage:**

when starting fresh container:

```
docker run -it <imagename:tag> /bin/bash
docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash imagename:tag
```

when connecting to existing container:

```
docker exec -it <containerid or containername> /bin/bash
```